# Will Riot delete my account because of inactivity?

Tags: league-of-legends

My computer doesn't work, so I will not be able to play  League of Legends again for some months. Will Riot delete my account because of inactivity?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, if you ask them. No (if it's through the automated garbage collection system) as they do not delete accounts if inactive (never logged in from anywhere) for at least 2 years... But your name will become avaliable for others.

Answer (score 27):

They will **not** remove your account:

> Will I lose my content if my account becomes inactive?
>
> No! Account content (Champions, Skins, RP, etc) can never be lost through inactivity. Only your Summoner Name will be affected.

However, you will loose League Points (LP) and maybe even ranks. Your name can also become available to be claimed after 6 + (each summoner level above 6) months.

[source](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201751914-Summoner-Name-Clean-Up-#q1)

Comment: I believe that you will not lose ranks via decay unless you are gold or higher (except of course if a new season starts)

Comment: @MatthewPigram They changed it so Gold also has no decay. http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mmr

Answer (score 2):

Riot deactivates Korean accounts if they are inactive for >1 month.
You can easily reactivate them using your phone number / ssn etc.
Accounts on other region are safe.

Answer (score -1):

Many people find that after a few months of inactivity Riot will take everything away without explanation and the ticketing system will do nothing. Don't invest too much time into this company cause they love blowing up accounts and then acting like nothing was ever there. Just Google it, you see the same story thousands of times over.

Comment: [Riot's policy on inactive accounts](https://support-leagueoflegends.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201751914), as linked in the other answer, states that only the summoner name is subject to being lost if the account is left inactive. Nothing else is "taken away". If you have evidence to the contrary that's relevant (i.e. not very old) and credible (i.e. has evidence) then I urge you to [edit] this answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).